# Android :connectedAndroidTest can't find symbol .. -> BuildConfigField gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I've set up some custom build tasks with gradle(Android Project), now those tasks work fine. Example of this task:

```
TEST {
    buildConfigField "String", "KEY", "\"..\""
    buildConfigField "String", "CLIENT_ID", "\"\""
    buildConfigField "String", "PROTOCOL_VERSION", "\"5.0.0\""
    buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_ENVIRONMENT", "\"..\""
    buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_COUNTRY", "\"..\""

    debuggable true
    jniDebuggable true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}
```

Now the problem is, that when I run the predefined task `connectedAndroidTest` it complains about missing variables in the code, which are the `BuildConfigFields` that aren't recognised. So my question how to work around this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: When I've had problem with BuildConfig I needed to restart android studio (even clean build wasn't help me)

Comment: Thanks but still, `Error:(51, 60) error: cannot find symbol variable KEY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define variables for `debug` `buildType` (just for debug builds)):

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "KEY", "\"..\""
        buildConfigField "String", "CLIENT_ID", "\"\""
        buildConfigField "String", "PROTOCOL_VERSION", "\"5.0.0\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_ENVIRONMENT", "\"..\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_COUNTRY", "\"..\""
    }
}
```

or in `defaultConfig` (for all builds):

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "String", "KEY", "\"..\""
    buildConfigField "String", "CLIENT_ID", "\"\""
    buildConfigField "String", "PROTOCOL_VERSION", "\"5.0.0\""
    buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_ENVIRONMENT", "\"..\""
    buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_COUNTRY", "\"..\""
}
```